# Очень медленно производится цикл по большим массивам данных. Как ускорить?

Tags: php, оптимизация

Формирую отчет из БД. Данные получаю +- за 1 сек.
Строк 300 000+. Необходимо производить некоторые манипуляции в каждой итерации. Одна итерация выполняется в среднем 0.003 сек. Итог - больше 15 минут производится цикл. В результате формируется ассоциативный массив с суммарной информацией (50 строк примерно). Но это очень долго.

Вопрос: Есть предположения как ускорить или кто какие использует фишки для ускорения работы с большим объёмом данных?

*update:*

Производимые манипуляции:

```
      if (!isset($consumption[$material_name]['category_name'])) {
        $consumption[$material_name]['category_name'] = $category_name;
      }

      if (!isset($consumption[$material_name]['material_name'])) {
        $consumption[$material_name]['material_name'] = $material_name;
      }

      if (isset($consumption[$material_name][$date])) {
        $consumption[$material_name][$date] += $consumption_value;
      } else {
        $consumption[$material_name][$date] = $consumption_value;
      }

      if (isset($consumption_by_invoices["{$material_name}_$date"][$invoice_id])) {
        $consumption_by_invoices["{$material_name}_$date"][$invoice_id] += $consumption_value;
      } else {
        $consumption_by_invoices["{$material_name}_$date"][$invoice_id] = $consumption_value;
      }
```

Comment: sql запрос хде примерный

Comment: @Kvandaik он огромный и к сути вопроса не относится

Comment: Что за манипуляции?

Comment: @MBo формирование нового ассоциативного массива с группировкой по ключам. Добавил код

Comment: надо смотреть на весь код. Возможно там проблема известного маляра.

Comment: Для таких дел обычно создаются хранимые процедуры так как нет смысла извлекать данные в код, а делать все вычисления в движке БД.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Тоже думал в эту сторону, но пока не пробовал. Если других вариантов не будет, то буду писать процедуру, хотя бы время оценить

Comment: @radar4ick вы через секунду не целиком данные из базы получаете, вы просто начинаете их читать. База данных не отправляет вам сразу весь результирующий набор, вы получите вторую строку только прочитав первую. Если вы оставите цикл, но уберёте манипуляции, скорее всего, цикл не станет сильно быстрее.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин но если вывести результат запроса через dd() в Laravel, я вижу все данные целиком и если убрать цикл вообще и вернуть данные без обработки - время ограничивается только выборкой в 1 секунду.

Comment: @radar4ick а вы уверены в этом? dd может работать хитрее (напечатает первые n строк и поставит троеточие) чем какой-нибудь print_r. Просто не верится, что запись в stdout быстрее присвоения в массиве. Есть, конечно, вариант, что дело в памяти и у вас начинается сброс в какой-нибудь swap-файл, но это очень маловероятно. Сделайте  `while ($row = $sth->fetch()) { echo $row['id'] . "\n"; }` (или как там у вас). Неужели всё это будет быстрее присвоения в массив?

Comment: @radar4ick и [попрофилируйте](https://highload.today/profilirovanie-php-s-xhprof/) ваш скрипт. Предполагать хорошо, но знать наверняка ещё лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый очевидный способ ускорить выполнение операций в больших циклах -- разделить цикл на циклы поменьше и запустить их параллельно.

Было:

```
<?php // test.php

$start = time();
$result = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i) {
    ++$result;
    usleep(100);
}

printf("%d\nза %d сек\n", $result, time() - $start);
```

Стало:

```
<?php // test.php

if (count($argv) > 1) {
    [, $limit] = $argv;
    $result = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; ++$i) {
        ++$result;
        usleep(100);
    }
    echo "$result\n";
    exit(0);
} else {
    $start = time();
    exec('echo 25000 25000 25000 25000 | xargs -P 4 -n 1 php test.php', $results);
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $sum += (int) $result;
    }

    printf("%d\nза %d сек\n", $sum, time() - $start);
}
```

Comment: Воспользоваться многопоточностью...это интересно. Предлагаете использовать сторонние расширения?

Comment: @radar4ick можно любые инструменты, которые есть в вашем распоряжении. Можно нафоркать процессов из php, можно использовать утилиты типа xargs, можно переписать на go.